# Combining enumerate and align works in theorem environment, but not outside the theorem environment

Tags: align, amsmath, theorems, enumerate, amsthm

I was using MWE 1 (which worked fine), but now I want to get rid of the theorem environment (MWE 2). However, that does not work and I get the following error. Any idea how I can make MWE 2 work?

---

**Error**

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

1.14      \end{align}
                     %
```

---

**MWE 1**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}%

\begin{theorem}%
\begin{enumerate}%
    \begin{align}%
    \intertext{\item Condition $A$}
    a &= b
    \intertext{\item Condition $B$}
    c &= d
    \end{align}%
\end{enumerate}%
\end{theorem}%

\end{document}%
```

**MWE 2**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}%

\begin{enumerate}%
    \begin{align}%
    \intertext{\item Condition $A$}
    a &= b
    \intertext{\item Condition $B$}
    c &= d
    \end{align}%
\end{enumerate}%

\end{document}%
```

Comment: You have to put the first item outside the `align`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi That works, thank you. Weird that inside the theorem environment I did not encounter the error.

Comment: the `theorem` environment in `amsthm` is defined using a list, so `\item` has already been invoked before the `enumerate`.  just one idiosyncrasy of the internals that one shouldn't have to know about, but occasionally sticks up to be tripped over.  by the way, it doesn't hurt *within* a theorem to put an `\item` directly after `enumerate`; in fact, it would be a good idea, because it reinforces a good habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the best practises for theorems, but the normal way is that you need at least one `\item` outside the math mode. Please have a look on my second example which is the correct syntax here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}    
\begin{theorem}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{align}
            \intertext{\item Condition $A$}
            a &= b
            \intertext{\item Condition $B$}
            c &= d
        \end{align}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}       
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Condition $A$ % move this out from the align
    \begin{align}           
        a &= b
        \intertext{\item Condition $B$}
        c &= d
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic: `\shortintertext{}` would look better here.

Personally I would go like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext  
\begin{theorem}\leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\widthof{Condition \textit{A}},label=Condition \Alph*,itemindent=4em,leftmargin=!]
        \item
        \begin{align}
            a &= b
            \shortintertext{\item\mbox}
            c &= d
        \end{align}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}       
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\widthof{Condition \textit{A}},label=Condition \Alph*,itemindent=4em,leftmargin=!]
    \item
    \begin{align}           
        a &= b
        \shortintertext{\item\mbox}
        c &= d
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see my comment on the question itself regarding `theorem` and `\item`.